# Solr : How can I group on two different fields?

Tags: solr

My schema is like :

```
product_id  
category_id
```

A category contains products.
In solr 3.6, I group results on category_id and it works well.

I just added a new field:

```
group_id
```

A group contains products that vary on size or color.
Example: shoes in blue, red and yellow are 3 differents products and have the same group_id.

Additionally to the result grouping on field category_id, I would like to have in my results only one product for a group_id, assuming group_id can be null (for products that aren't part of a group).

To follow the example of the shoes, it means that for the request "shoe", only one of the 3 products should be in results.

I thought to do a second result grouping on group_id, but I doesn't seem possible to do that way.

Any idea?

EDIT : For now, i process the results in php to delete documents that have a group_id that is already in the results. I leave this subject open, in case someone finds how to group on 2 fields

Comment: Seems like many people want to search for that. Heres a couple things, it may not reflect the cutting edge of Solr: http://www.slideshare.net/MarkHarwood/proposal-for-nested-document-support-in-lucene http://blog.griddynamics.com/2011/07/solr-experience-search-parent-child.html

Answer (score 9):

If your aim is to get grouping counts based on multiple "group by" fields, you can use **pivot faceting** to achieve this.

```
&facet.pivot=category_id,group_id
```

Solr will give you back a hierarchy of grouped result counts, following the page of search results, under the `facet_pivot` element.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters?highlight=%28pivot%29#Pivot_.28ie_Decision_Tree.29_Faceting

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Never heard of facet.pivot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to group by query on two fields.
If you need count then you can use `facet.field`(For single field) or `facet.pivot`(For multiple field).
It is not actually group but you can get count of that group for multiple field.

Example Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <bool name="zkConnected">true</bool>
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">306</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="667" start="0" maxScore="0.70710677">
        <doc>
            <int name="idField">7393</int>
            <int name="field_one">12</int>
        </doc>
    </result>
    <lst name="facet_counts">
        <lst name="facet_queries"/>
        <lst name="facet_fields"/>
        <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
        <lst name="facet_intervals"/>
        <lst name="facet_heatmaps"/>
        <lst name="facet_pivot">
            <arr name="field_one,field_two">
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">field_one</str>
                    <int name="value">3</int>
                    <int name="count">562</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">field_two</str>
                            <bool name="value">true</bool>
                            <int name="count">347</int>
                        </lst>
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">field_two</str>
                            <bool name="value">false</bool>
                            <int name="count">215</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
                <lst>
                    <str name="field">field_one</str>
                    <int name="value">12</int>
                    <int name="count">105</int>
                    <arr name="pivot">
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">field_two</str>
                            <bool name="value">true</bool>
                            <int name="count">97</int>
                        </lst>
                        <lst>
                            <str name="field">field_two</str>
                            <bool name="value">false</bool>
                            <int name="count">8</int>
                        </lst>
                    </arr>
                </lst>
            </arr>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

Example Query :

```
http://192.168.100.145:7983/solr/<collection>/select?facet.pivot=field_one,field_two&facet=on&fl=idField,field_one&indent=on&q=field_one:(3%2012)&rows=1&wt=xml
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can change the data that you are posting to solr, then I suggest that you create a string field which will have a concatenation of category_id and group_id. For example, if the category_id = 5 and group_id=2, then your string field can be :- '5,2' (using ',' or any other character as a delimiter). You can then group on this string field.

Comment: clever, but not suitable for my case. I want to group on category_id, with a limit of 10000, and then group on group_id with a limit of 1, because only 1 document per group_id has to return.