# Does Solr support group multiple fields?

Tags: solr, group-by, field

I am newer to solr, we want to get document list of each group that grouped by multi-fields. And I finds solr supports grouping-result, but this feature supports just one field. And I also finds ReduceStream support multiple-fields, but the results set of ReduceStream are not like group-format. The parallel Sql feature can group by multi-fields, but cat not get document list of each group. My question is that: is there any ways to group result by multiple fields and the result set show as grouping-result feature.

```
Any help will be appreciated.
```

Note：I want to get document list of each group not the aggregation of each group, so facet.pivot, RollupStream etc can not match my question.
And I find that ElasticSearch can statify my question by using terms aggregation(child aggregation) and top-hints metric aggregation.

Comment: flagging as off topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr : How can I group on two different fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758829/solr-how-can-i-group-on-two-different-fields)

Comment: Hi, I have found this post before, but it is not my situation. I wants to get **document list** of each group not aggregations of each group.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to merge the two fields at indexing time, in a third field e.g.
group_title = title + category