# How to sort Solr results by a field having exact value and divide into buckets at the same time

Tags: solr

I have an index in Solr similar to this:

```
url         outcome  owner time
/api/helo1  OK       Ref1  14:50
/api/helo1  OK       Ref1  15:00
/api/helo1  OK       Ref1  15:01
/api/helo1  KO       Ref1  15:02
/api/helo1  KO       Ref1  15:03
/api/work2  OK       Ref2  15:00
/api/work2  OK       Ref2  15:01
/api/work2  OK       Ref2  15:02
/api/work2  KO       Ref2  15:02
/api/work2  OK       Ref2  15:03
/api/work2  OK       Ref2  15:04
```

I need to create a query that returns the results in a bucket form but that also has a specific order based on the counts in a specific bucket, like this :

```
 "facets": {
    "count": 11,
    "outcomeStatsForApi": {
        "buckets": [
            {
                "val": "/api/work2",
                "count": 6,
                "outcomes": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "val": "OK",
                            "count": 5
                        }, 
                        {
                            "val": "KO",
                            "count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "val": "/api/helo1",
                "count": 5,
                "outcomes": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "val": "OK",
                            "count": 3
                        }, 
                        {
                            "val": "KO",
                            "count": 2
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
       ]
   }
}
```

so in this case the order of results in the bucket "outcomeStatsForApi" is: the "url" that have the MAX number of records with outcome=OK is the first one .

I'd like also to be able to modify the order in which the results appear: for example having the results with the MAX number of "KO" counts first.

How can one achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I am not able to get your requirement properly.
As soon as I understand you are looking for multilevel group count.
and you can archive this with `facet` query.

For single level you can use `facet.field` and for multi level `facet.pivot` and it will return output like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885515/4392892) and for more detail you also can refer [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html)

Comment: My requirement is basically to get the list of "url" ordered by number of "OK" counts (asc or des) and I need also the counts for "KO" outcomes in the same result list result list. So for each "url" I need to know how many times the outcome was "OK", how many times it was "KO" and the order of the complete result list has to be based on the number of OK outcomes.

Comment: Okay then you can do that also by using `facet.sort` with `facet.pivot`.